# Error in WebStorm editor for JavaScript version

Tags: javascript, webstorm

So this project is in JavaScript. In

```
Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> JavaScript language version
```

I selected

```
EECMAScript 6
```

When I then open a JavaScript file and have this line:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
```

I see that has a red underline and the message is:

```
"JSHint: const is available in ES6 (use esversion: 6)"
```

Why? Am I not using version 6? Or what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the version also in JSHint, if you want to use that linter.

More about this here:

http://jshint.com/docs/options/#esversion

[image]